# why does "Release Connection" execute in catch{} block and in finally{} block for jdbcTemplate#execute

Tags: java, jdbc

```
public <T> T execute(ConnectionCallback<T> action) throws DataAccessException {
    Assert.notNull(action, "Callback object must not be null");

    Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(getDataSource());
    try {
        Connection conToUse = con;
        if (this.nativeJdbcExtractor != null) {
            // Extract native JDBC Connection, castable to OracleConnection or the like.
            conToUse = this.nativeJdbcExtractor.getNativeConnection(con);
        }
        else {
            // Create close-suppressing Connection proxy, also preparing returned Statements.
            conToUse = createConnectionProxy(con);
        }
        return action.doInConnection(conToUse);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        // Release Connection early, to avoid potential connection pool deadlock
        // in the case when the exception translator hasn't been initialized yet.
        DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
        con = null;
        throw getExceptionTranslator().translate("ConnectionCallback", getSql(action), ex);
    }
    finally {
        DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
    }
}
```

Comment: i think "releaseConnection" just need to be executed in the finally{} block,isn't it?

Comment: Do you mean, why is there a call to `releaseConnection` in both locations?

Comment: yes ,i don't understand

Comment: Evidently someone thought throwing an exception meant the `finally` block would not execute.  Whoever thought that was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment in the `catch (SQLException ex)` block, whoever wrote this code was taking into consideration that the following line may take some time to run on its initial call:

```
throw getExceptionTranslator().translate("ConnectionCallback", getSql(action), ex);
```

While the SQLException is getting translated, they didn't want the connection to still be held unnecessarily; therefore, they release it first.

Keep in mind that although a translated expectation is going to be thrown, the code in the finally block is going to be run before the exception is thrown to the caller; however, the finally block will run after these method calls: `getExceptionTranslator().translate("ConnectionCallback", getSql(action), ex)`

Another way to see this is with the following, equivalent, code:

```
catch (SQLException ex) {
    // Release Connection early, to avoid potential connection pool deadlock
    // in the case when the exception translator hasn't been initialized yet.
    DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
    con = null;

    // create the translated exception
    Exception et = getExceptionTranslator().translate("ConnectionCallback", getSql(action), ex);

    // throw the translated exception
    throw et;
}
finally {
     // release the connection.
     // If a SQLException is caught above, then this will run before 
     // the translated exception is thrown to the caller
     DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
}
```

Furthermore, they figured it wouldn't hurt to try and release the connection again in the finally block even if it may have already been released in the catch block. This assumes that releasing an already released or null connection has no effect.

It's also worth noting that regardless of a SQLException being throw in the try block, you still want to try and release the connection. Hence, the need for doing so in the finally block.

Comment: // Release Connection early, to avoid potential connection pool deadlock in the case when the exception translator hasn't been initialized yet.
Which case will cause  connection pool deadlock?

Comment: There's no telling if it will cause connection pool deadlock - it's really just a matter of giving the connection back to the pool sooner than later so that other threads are waiting less time on getting a connection.